# How can I determine if a ruby gem is actually a native C extension?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I determine if a ruby gem is actually a native C extension?

When running `gem install some_gem` I can see when it tries to build the native extension, but is there a way to determine which of the gems are native C extensions before installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the gem specification to see if [`extensions`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#extensions) is defined. You have to download the gem or check its source to do this, but it's not to difficult to do programmatically with a bit of unix-fu:

```sh
curl -L <gem-url> | tar xOf - metadata.gz | gunzip | ruby -r yaml -e 'p YAML.load($stdin.read).extensions.any?'
```

Let's compare [bson](https://rubygems.org/gems/bson) & [bson_ext](https://rubygems.org/gems/bson_ext) (since they're the first non-C-extension and C-extension versions of the same gem I could think of):

```sh
% curl -L https://rubygems.org/downloads/bson-1.8.0.gem | tar xOf - metadata.gz | gunzip | ruby -r yaml -e 'p YAML.load($stdin.read).extensions.any?'
false

% curl -L https://rubygems.org/downloads/bson_ext-1.8.0.gem | tar xOf - metadata.gz | gunzip | ruby -r yaml -e 'p YAML.load($stdin.read).extensions.any?'
true
```

You could automate the need to know the current version of the gem by using the [RubyGems API](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/):

```sh
curl https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/bson.yaml | ruby -r yaml -e 'p YAML.load($stdin.read)["version"]'
```